# Using @helpers from another View in Razor ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

I want to write a few simple `@helpers` to use in several views.
I want them to be inside a Razor .cshtml file (not in a c# class) to have the HTML syntax highlighted.

I can easily access `@helpers` written within the same View, I can separate them into `Helpers.cshtml`, and if I put this `Helpers.cshtml` into an App_Code folder I can access it from any View via `@Helpers.MyHelper()`. But I want them to be accessible only for a few pages.

I think, it could be like putting a @using if the helpers are in c# class, but what is the namespace for just another view?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but that's not possible with helpers stored in the `App_Code` folder as `.cshtml` files. They will be shared among all views.

Comment: thanks. I've just named it more specifically and put in the App_Code.